# Error distributing WPF app that uses EF Code first

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a WPF that generates an SQLCE DB at runtime and fills it.

Everything runs fine in debug, but when I distribute an app to a 64bit Windows 7 machine I get a

```
 Access to the database file is not allowed
```

error because the system cannot create the `.sdf` file. I think it's a permission issue but I don't know what I can do to avoid this problem, is there anything to do in setup project or a flag to give to Entity Framework for forcing DB creation?

Answer (score 0):

Create the sdf file in a location where the user has write access.